# Wxpython mp3 player on raspberry pi

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, wxpython

I found this mp3 player for wxpython http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/20/wxpython-creating-a-simple-mp3-player/
It works fine on windows, but now I want to play the music on my raspberry pi. 
But it gives an error that it can't play the music files. So what's wrong? Do I have to install another mediaplayer on the raspberry pi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help matters if you posted what the error was.
However, I suspect that loading `libwxgtk-media2.8-0` and any dependencies would probably help.
Notes:
There is also `libwxgtk-media3.0-0` for later versions of wxpython
I believe that on Linux/Rpi it uses gstreamer0.10 which is, arguably, now defunct.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. First it says "could not load a suitable video sink" and then the error handler in the script shows a message with "unsupported format". But I tried vlc out. And now I made my musicplayer with vlc.

Comment: Glad to hear that you resolved your problem. Using `vlc.py` is very simple for the basics.